# A music video from the 2000s and it’s from a band (alternative is the genre)

Tags: identify-this-song, alternative-rock

I’m trying to find this song I remember listening to as a child. I don’t know the lyrics but I vaguely remember the scene, there was the band (around 3 white 20ish year old guys) and they are playing/singing at the beach. There’s a scene where a lifeguard sees a boy drowning and brings the boy back to shore and saves him with cpr. That’s all I can really remember. I hope it’s enough and someone can find it, because I’ve been trying to find it for a few days now.

Comment: You forgot to describe the music itself, we are a *music* fans community :-)

Comment: I mean I don’t remember much cause it’s from a long time ago but I remember a guy with shaggy hair playing the guitar under a bridge at the beach and there was other people too, a drummer and another guitarist I think. What else do I need to answer?

Answer (score 2):

Someone asked this same question on [yahoo answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100411134425AAghAow)  and the answer given was [Switchfoot - Dare You To Move](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOTcr9wKC-o).

Answer (score 0):

Switch foot date you to move I think this is the song you are looking for!!!!!!